# How to Iterate over a dynamic keys object in typescript

Tags: typescript

Noob question, I Can't seem to find a way to interate an object with dynamic keys in typescript

```
//This is how i type my object
let obj : { [ key : string ], string } = {};
```

and using forEach or map doesn't work and giving me errors. Pls help

Comment: Can you also show your attempt and the errors you get?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
for (const key in obj) {
  // Logic here
}
```

"key" will store each individual key for every iteration of the loop, and you can use obj[key] to get the value.

Also, if you're making an object with key-value pairs of type string and string, use

```
let obj: Record<string, string> = {};
```

Record is a good type to use for string-string objects.

It would be helpful if you posted exactly what error you were encountering!

Comment: Thanks! your solution worked. Sorry for the noob question.

Comment: Great to hear that!